Scroll to id from menu item hash(#) to different page not working properly. I am using locomotive and Gsap animation
https://cutandshave.festcode.com/
I have passed id in the service page named "packages" and then pass hash value (https://cutandshave.festcode.com/service#packages) to the menu item for packages. But when I scrolled to related section while screen has come.
Attempt multiple trial but none is working for me. What can I try next?
// Scroll to the ID specified in the URL (if present)
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const hash = window.location.hash; // Get the hash from the URL
  if (hash) {
    const targetElement = document.querySelector(hash); // Select the element by the ID
    if (targetElement) {
      scroll.scrollTo(targetElement); // Use Locomotive Scroll's scrollTo method
    }
  }
});
// Update Locomotive Scroll after all images and media have loaded
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  scroll.update(); // Recalculate scroll position to avoid white space
});

